# Htaccess rewrite url and remove part from url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

Hi I'm trying to do the following.

When the domain is accessed through http it should redirect to https.
When domain contains www it should redirect to https
When domain contains language abbreviation it should remove it.

Possible urls:

1: http://www.example.com/en/how-did-it-all-start

2: http://example.com/en/how-did-it-all-start

3: http://www.example.com/how-did-it-all-start

These domains should redirect with one 301 redirect to
https://example.com/how-did-it-all-start

I have tried numerous things but nothing seams to work when I'm trying to combine it with the www. It now only works for http urls, when I add the www to it, it breaks.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^en/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%/%2% [R=301,L]
```

I don't know how to properly combine those to conditions without breaking it.
Tried to do in different ways but until now no success.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `[OR]` clauses in your conditional with optional matches to handle all 3 cases:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:en/)?(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, but the above still doesn't work properly I have the same result only http requests are being redirected properly. When I add www to it, it breaks. Any clew ? Or do you maybe need some more information?

Comment: What do you mean by **breaks**? Did you clear your browser cache? Also keep this rule right below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: I've tested this rule independently and it works for all 3 conditions.

Comment: Ok then maybe something else is wrong!
http://www.staka-roofaccesshatches.dev.100.nl/en/about-us/who-is-staka/how-did-it-all-start

This is my development url and here it doesn't work however it does when you use non www url.

Comment: Ok so development is a problem because there is no www configured.
I also placed it on the live machine there it says it is not properly redirected, it is in a endless loop!

Comment: The virtual host for live domain is exactly the same as this one. Only with proper domain.


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.co.uk
        ServerAlias example.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.co.uk/www/httpdocs/
        CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/example.co.uk/_logs/www/access_log combined
        ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/example.co.uk/_logs/www/error_log
</VirtualHost>

Comment: There is no endless loop but there is some other rule/code which is adding `www` or `https -> http` or `/en/`. Can you post your full .htaccess?

Comment: This is the link to the file: https://staka-roofaccesshatches.dev.100.nl/htaccess.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139601/discussion-between-anubhava-and-iason).